# Sending array data from server to client in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, mediawiki-api

So I'm trying to send my data from my server code to my client code, yet it's returning undefined. Not sure what to do as I've been stuck here for a while.

I used these packages:
https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiki-infobox

```js
Rappers = new Mongo.Collection(null)
var page = 'Tupac'
var language = 'en'
var rappers = null
var texts
var rappers2
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  getGists = function getGists(user, callback) {
    Meteor.call('getGists', user, callback);
  }
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    rappers2 = []

    function call(text, callback) {
      Meteor.call('getWikiStuff', rappers2, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result)

      })

      var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        callback()
      }, 4000)
    }

    function consoleit() {
      console.log(rappers2)

    }
    call('hello', consoleit)

  })
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.methods({
      getWikiStuff: function(rappers3) {
        var infobox = Meteor.npmRequire('wiki-infobox')
        var bound = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(callback) {
          callback()
        });
        console.log("HERE")
        bound(function() {
          infobox(page, language, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              return
            }
            rappers = data.associated_acts
            for (var x = 0; x < rappers.length; x++)
              if (rappers[x].text != undefined) {
                var yo = rappers[x].text
                rappers3.push(yo)
              }
            for (var value of rappers3)
              console.log(value)

          })
        })

        return rappers3
      }

    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why your getWikiStuff ONLY runs in server, and is nested in Meteor.startup?

Comment: Do either of your console.logs return data? Cam you show the output?